# embed and share options not working no errors on console

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling

HI I am trying to implement an embed and share options for one of my webpages. Not sure why but the code wont do anything and its not showing any errors on console.

fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/jt129L49/2/

```
function embedButton() {

        d3.select('.btn-embed').on ("click", function() {
            d3.select('.Stage-popup').hide();
            d3.select('.Stage-popup-embed').show();
        });
        d3.select('.btn-faq').on ("click", function() 
                                  { d3.select('.Stage-popup').hide(); 
                                   d3.select('.Stage-popup-faq').show(); });
        d3.select('.Stage-popup .popup-close-btn').on ("click", function() { d3.select('.Stage-popup').hide() });
}
```

Comment: I can't see where do you call to the `embedButton` function..

Comment: @MoshFeu: Opps sorry I added the call now But in still wont work

Comment: Where? I still can't see it. Can you, please,  update your fiddle?

Comment: here sorry was just going to post it above in a minute https://jsfiddle.net/jt129L49/5/

Comment: Well, there are errors in the console.. When you click `d3.select(...).hide is not a function`. I'm not familiar with d3.js but I can't find the `show/hide` functions in the docs. Why can't you do the same thing with jQuery (From what I see you use it).

Comment: @MoshFeu: I am not very familiar with jquery. That is why I am using d3 here

Comment: Are you sure that there are `show/hide` functions in d3? If so, please refer the relevant doc. If not, I can show you how to so do this with `jQuery`,